# 21 CFR part 11 validation for SAAS

Tags: validation, saas

In a FDA regulated environment applications need to be validated. I've done that tons of times in my career but now I'm facing SAAS. Has anyone out there faced this before? Any FDA related guideline on this scheme?

Besides some black box approach and much support from the provider I see this as hard to do.

Comment: I think you have this tagged wrong.  You have it tagged as SSAS (Sql Server Analysis Services), but I think you wanted to tag it as SAAS (Software as a service)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear  ya!

It is impossible...

check out: http://www.vantagesystems.com/Library/Pharmaceutical%20Commerce_Article_%20IMPROVING%20ERP%20IN%20THE%20LIFE%20SCIENCES%20INDUSTRY.pdf

Since original link is dead, here's a wayback machine archive link for the same article
https://web.archive.org/web/20100601233736/http://www.vantagesystems.com/Library/Pharmaceutical%20Commerce_Article_%20IMPROVING%20ERP%20IN%20THE%20LIFE%20SCIENCES%20INDUSTRY.pdf

Comment: That's what I thought but wnated to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to run a validated SaaS for medical devices.

In fact here is [QPharma's perspective](http://validationandregulatorycompliance.blogspot.com/2010/10/best-practices-for-validation-of.html?goback=.gmp_3514955.gde_3514955_member_32646802) on this.

Note I am not affiliated with QPharma, but I am very much interested in SaaS and validation techniques. The point is it is indeed quite possible!